# What's the meaning of "by one count"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> Only 2.4% of the 113th Congresss were Asian-Americans; **by one count**,
>   fewer than 2% of state legislators are.

What's the meaning of "by one count"?

Comment: Please provide a link to the source, or at least tell us where you found this. ([Here's why](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many things only estimates of the number of people is possible, for example numbers of people at an unticketed public event, or the number of people who watch a television program. There are several methods of making those estimates. Hence `by one count` refers to the number generated by one of the (possibly many) method of estimating the count.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wictionary, the noun *count* has the following meaning:

> The act of counting or tallying a quantity.
>
> Give the chairs a quick count to check if we have enough.

It is not *extremely* difficult to count how many Asian-Americans are sitting in Congress (2.4%) and 50 states' legislatures (fewer than 2%).

They just **counted** all of them **once** and it revealed the fact.